# How to import a 2D Array into a JTable from a CSV file

Tags: java, database, swing, csv, passwordvault

I am trying to implement a text file database system through a CSV file into a Java GUI, I have created the GUI, the database, the methods required to import and export to the file, and the method to convert the information into a 2DArray from the CSV file. I am trying to make a simple password vault but whenever I try adding something to the file I get an error stating:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at TextFileDatabase.readDatabase(TextFileDatabase.java:93)
    at PasswordVault.<init>(PasswordVault.java:97)
    at PasswordVault.main(PasswordVault.java:22)
```

The method that is returning the error is the readDatabase() one and it is as follows:

```
public static String[][] readDatabase()
    {
        try
        {
            kb = new Scanner(database);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //since the size of the database is unknown, we'll first work in a temporary 2D arraylist that can dynamically change its size
        ArrayList<String[]> tempDatabase = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        while(kb.hasNext()) 
        {
            String tempLine = kb.nextLine(); //reads the first/next line of the database
            String[] tempData = tempLine.split(","); //gets that result as a string, splits it up into an array based on commas
            tempDatabase.add(tempData); //adds the string array to the arraylist
        }

        //at this point, the while loop should have traversed through the entire file

        String[][] output = new String[tempDatabase.size()][3];
            //this is the string we'll return
            //the column size is the size of the tempDatabase arraylist because thats the number of passwords we have stored
            //the row size is three because each row is an 1) app, 2) password, 3) description 

        //converts the ArrayList to the actual output array

        for(int x=0; x<output.length; x++)
        {
            for(int y=0; y<3; y++)
            {
                //This is line 93 in TextFileDatabase()
                output[x][y] = tempDatabase.get(x)[y];
            }
        }

        return output;
    }
```

and it is pointing to this section of code in my PasswordVault() class

```
        //This is line 97
        String[][] data = TextFileDatabase.readDatabase();

        //This will convert the information from the 2DArray made from the file into a table model to use in the GUI 
        for(int a = 0; a < data.length; a++)
        {
            String[] row = new String[data[a].length];

            for(int b = 0; b < data[a].length; b++)
            {
                row[b] = data[a][b];
            }

            tableModel.addRow(row);
        }
```

And the last line the error calls to is just the line calling the PasswordVault() constructor

```
new PasswordVault();
```

Comment: *//This is line 97* - yes, well the problem is on line 93 of your TextFieldDatabase class in the readDatabase() method.

Comment: @camickr thank you for that, what is wrong with it

Comment: I have no idea. I don't know what line 93 is. Do some basic debugging and see why the array is empty. Why are you trying to convert to a 2D array? Just keep each row of data in the ArrayLIst. *the while loop should have traversed through the entire file* - don't add a comment in your code. Do some debugging to see the size of the ArrayLIst to make sure there is data.

Comment: @camickr "output[x][y] = tempDatabase.get(x)[y];" is line 93 as I stated in the comment, I am converting to a 2d array so I can convert it into a tableModel

Comment: *as I stated in the comment* - yes, will given you have all kinds of comments in the code that line doesn't stand out. 1) Again, what debugging have you done? We don't have access to your data. Did you verify data was read into the ArrayList? Did you verify the size of the Array created by the split() method? 2) There is no need to convert it to a 2D array to add the data to the TableModel. You just use iterate through the ArrayList and invoke the addRow(…) method for each row in the ArrayList.

Comment: @camickr When I run the debugger, I get the error "[[App Name, App Password, Description], [null, null, null]]".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210842/discussion-between-blake-and-camickr).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
output[x][y] = tempDatabase.get(x)[y];
```

TempDatabase try to access a inexistent location. You have 3 elements em ALL strings[] inside tempdatabase? Check it.

Comment: what do you mean by that